# Firefox add-ons to convert XML into XHTML

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any Firefox add-on to convert XML into XHTML?
I wanted to display xml file in proper look and feel.

Currently I am getting this error msg.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox can do exacty what you want without an addon. However, you need some [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) data to do so. Without XSLT, no program knows, how to display it correctly.

Comment: So in order to display xml what should I do.

Comment: @VishnudevK You need the XSL and include it in the xml-file as xml-stylesheet. I don't know from where you get the xml-data, but most likely, you'll need to create such a stylesheet on your own. Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858345/xsltwhich-is-the-best-tutorial-you-would-like-to-recommend

Comment: That's the problem.  I am getting this xml file dynamically from "Fatwire" support tool. They doesn't associated any XSL file with XML.